# Cannot scroll in terminal of minecraft server

Tags: command-line, minecraft, scrolling

I don't know if this it the right place to ask,
but i wanted to try anyway.

When i run my Minecraft server on Ubuntu 18.10 i cannot scroll up on the terminal.
While i can scroll in the normal terminal with ease.

[image]

in the picture you can see that the scroll bar on the right is full, while there is loads of text above.

Hope someone can help me, or remove me if this is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: Shift + Pg_Up - try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrollbar is not shown if something switches to the so-called *alternate screen* of the terminal emulator. It could be the app in question, e.g. if it uses ncurses (which I doubt for something that produces a sequential output, as seen in your screenshot). `screen` and `tmux` also switch to this mode.

I'm not familiar with Minecraft server at all, but a random web find says to run it as `screen /home/minecraft/run.sh`. If that's what you do, it's `screen` that switches to this mode and not the minecraft `run.sh` itself.

You can run it without `screen`, in which case you lose the functionality provided by `screen`, e.g. to be able to detact and attach back later. Or you can use the scrolling capabilities (keyboard actions) provided by `screen` itself, consult `screen`'s documentation for what these keys are.

Comment: Thank you very much! I found out if I press crtl+a+esc i enter in copy mode, then i can scroll freely.